# Dynamic COUNTIF matrix with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a list, in where an item as an error judgement.
Now I want to count how many errors an items have.
Normally in excel I would use the COUNTIF function for that.
Build a "matrix". On Y-axis, the Items, on X-axis the errors. Fill the whole matrix with the COUNTIF, and from that I can make a chart.

But is this possible with VBA on a dynamic range?

[image]

At the end, I need the info that, for example, MA1AD1 has 4 BRIDGE errors

Comment: Use a Pivot Table?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Transform Data (PivotTable, VBA)

- Writing a code is nice, but how long will it take: half an hour, an hour, more?

**PivotTable**

- With a pivot table you can handle this in less than a minute.
- Select the range.
- Select `Insert>PivotTable>From Table/Range`.
- In the window that opens select the location (in the image e.g., `M1` of the existing worksheet).
- In the pivot table, drag the first column to `Rows`, the third to `Columns` and again, any of the two, to `Values` and play with it.

[image]

**VBA**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CountErrors()
    Const ProcName As String = "CountErrors"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    Const srCol As Long = 1
    Const scCol As Long = 3
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "E1"
    Dim dHeader As String: dHeader = "" ' Top-Left Header
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    With RefCurrentRegion(sws.Range(sFirstCellAddress))
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If srCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data or only headers
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
        If Len(dHeader) = 0 Then dHeader = .Cells(1)
    End With
    
    Dim srData As Variant: srData = GetRange(srg.Columns(srCol))
    Dim srDict As Object: Set srDict = DictColumnIncrement(srData, , 2)
    
    Dim scData As Variant: scData = GetRange(srg.Columns(scCol))
    Dim scDict As Object: Set scDict = DictColumnIncrement(scData, , 2)
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = srDict.Count + 1
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = scDict.Count + 1
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    ' Top-Left Header
    dData(1, 1) = dHeader
    ' Row Labels
    For Each Key In srDict.Keys
        dData(srDict(Key), 1) = Key
    Next Key
    ' Column Labels
    For Each Key In scDict.Keys
        dData(1, scDict(Key)) = Key
    Next Key
    ' Data
    For r = 1 To srCount
        If srDict.Exists(srData(r, 1)) Then
            If scDict.Exists(scData(r, 1)) Then
                dData(srDict(srData(r, 1)), scDict(scData(r, 1))) _
                    = dData(srDict(srData(r, 1)), scDict(scData(r, 1))) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    Erase srData: Erase scData: Set srDict = Nothing: Set scDict = Nothing
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, dcCount)
        .Resize(drCount).Value = dData
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount).Clear
        .Font.Bold = True ' headers
        .Resize(drCount - 1, 1).Offset(1).Font.Bold = True ' row labels
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Errors counted.", vbInformation
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a reference to the range starting with the first cell
'               of a range and ending with the last cell of the first cell's
'               Current Region.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefCurrentRegion( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "RefCurrentRegion"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With FirstCell.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        Set RefCurrentRegion = FirstCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count _
            - FirstCell.Row, .Column + .Columns.Count - FirstCell.Column)
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetRange"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the unique values from a column ('ColumnIndex')
'               of a 2D array ('Data') in the keys of a dictionary,
'               and returns an integer sequence in its items.
' Remarks:      Error values and blanks are excluded.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function DictColumnIncrement( _
    ByVal Data As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal FirstInteger As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal IntegerStep As Long = 1) _
As Object
    Const ProcName As String = "DictColumnIncrement"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    If IsMissing(ColumnIndex) Then
       c = LBound(Data, 2) ' use first column index
    Else
       c = CLng(ColumnIndex)
    End If
    
    Dim i As Long: i = FirstInteger
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        Key = Data(r, c)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(CStr(Key)) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
                    dict(Key) = i
                    i = i + IntegerStep
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
   
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function ' only error values and blanks
    
    Set DictColumnIncrement = dict

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: just wow! I wish I had this programming skills.
You are right about the amount of time it will take to program, but I'm using this for a collegue to make his life easier

Comment: can I ask you an additional issue? 
Now this is fixed for Sheet1
Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
How can I use this for Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3

Comment: Those constants at the beginning are there so you can easily change their values. When you're not sure, use the code in a new workbook and see what happens.